# Rails ActiveRecord Shovel (<<) Operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have code in my application that appends to a has_many relation with the "<<" operator like so:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :comments

    def add_comment(content)
        @new_comment = Comment.create(content)
        self.comments << @new_comment
    end
end
```

And it seems to work. I never really questioned it or wondered when it calls "save" (I guess I never had a strong understanding of when to call "save" to begin with).

However, it seems that the `after_save` hook on comments doesn't get activated in my `add_comment` function, which prompts me to ask:

How does the `<<` operator work in activerecord and where can I read more about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use the `shovel` operator (`<<`), Rails automatically saves the associated object. So, when you do this:

```
self.comments << @new_comment
```

`@new_comment` is added to the `comments` collection and instantly fires update SQL without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object, unless the parent object is a new record.

From [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> **collection<<(object, …)** Adds one or more objects to the collection by
>   creating associations in the join table (collection.push and
>   collection.concat are aliases to this method). Note that this
>   operation instantly fires update SQL without waiting for the save or
>   update call on the parent object, unless the parent object is a new
>   record.

Comment: Oh I see, I had alot of trouble searching for "<<" - nice to know it's called the "Shovel" operator :)

Comment: actually it saves the pushed record only if the "parent" item responds true  to "persisted?". If you call "<<" on a new_record it doesn't save on the db.

Answer (score 0):

collection<<(object, …)

> Adds one or more objects to the collection by creating associations in
>   the join table (collection.push and collection.concat are aliases to
>   this method) or by setting their foreign keys to the collection’s
>   primary key. Note that this operation instantly fires update SQL
>   without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object,
>   unless the parent object is a new record.

Example:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :users
  has_many   :avatars, through: :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_one    :avatar
end

class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

@group.avatars << Avatar.new   # this would work if User belonged_to Avatar rather than the other way around
```